# Unsupported Operand Types using pop()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make it so that I input the value of my groceries and it gives me the subtotal like a cash register, specifically using the `pop()` function. However, my code always returns an operand error at `subtotal = subtotal + purchase_amounts.pop()`. Did I not properly change the value to an `int`?

```
purchase_amounts = []
price = []
subtotal = 0

while price != "done":
    price = input("How much did groceries cost? If done, type 'done'")
    if price != "done":
        int(price)
        (purchase_amounts.append(price))


print(purchase_amounts)

while purchase_amounts != [ ]:
    subtotal = subtotal + purchase_amounts.pop()


print(subtotal)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        line 16, in 
>       subtotal = subtotal + purchase_amounts.pop() TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    int(price)
    (purchase_amounts.append(price))
```

you should have:

```
    purchase_amounts.append(int(price))
```

`int` **returns** the result of str-to-int conversion, does not change its argument in-place. Oh, and this:

```
while purchase_amounts != [ ]:
```

should be changed to:

```
while purchase_amounts:
```

– a non-empty list is *truthy*…

Comment: I agree on the first point, but `while purchase_amounts != [ ]` and `while purchase_amounts` both accomplish the same task. Why does it matter which one is used?

Comment: @anon to avoid verbiage, which makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: But to me, they both are equally easy to understand. In fact, a person new to programming would probably find the second option harder to understand, as they wouldn't know that an empty list equates to False in python.

Comment: @Anon well, let's assume it is a matter of personal preference, but there's also a matter of performance…

Comment: Ok, I'm willing to leave it at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change `int(price)` to `price = int(price)`.